# C# wpf listview add items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have problem with creating listview. I am new in C# and wpf too.
I have tried different methods of filling ListView items and I can not solve it, because the input array is NxN dimensions. I found instructions on Bindig but I can not apply them because I can not create an object of that type, because the input array is dynamic. 
I can fill header columns but no rows and columns with values. This code works but all values are together in one column.

```
public void PrintListView(ResultsTable results)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.GridView gv = new System.Windows.Controls.GridView();
        gv.AllowsColumnReorder = true;

        int j=0;
        foreach (DataColumn dc in results.Columns)
        {
            GridViewColumn gvCol = new GridViewColumn(); 
            gvCol.Header = results.Columns[j].ColumnName;
            gvCol.Width = 200;             
            gv.Columns.Add(gvCol); 
            j++;           
        }
        lbVysledky.View = gv;

        foreach (DataRow dr in results.Rows)
        {
            string[] array1 = new string[1000];
           // List<string> zoznam = new List<string>();
         //   ObservableCollection<string> kolekcia = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataColumn dc in results.Columns)
            {         
                array1[i] = dr[dc].ToString();
           //     zoznam.Add (dr[dc].ToString());
           //     kolekcia.Add(dr[dc].ToString());                 
                i++;
            }
           this.lbVysledky.Items.Add(new ListViewItem { Content = pole[0] + pole[1]});                 
        }                
    }
```

Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to populate the `ListView` by adding rows and columns one at a time.  This is not the approach to use when populating a `ListView`.  Instead, you add the `ItemsSource` (in this case, your results object) and tell the `ListView` what the `DisplayMemberBinding` is for each column, and it will display the proper values in each column for each row.

It probably just means modifying your loop where you add columns to the `ListView` to something like this:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in results.Columns)
{
    GridViewColumn gvCol = new GridViewColumn(); 
    gvCol.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(dc.ColumnName);        
    gvCol.Header = results.Columns[j].ColumnName;
    gvCol.Width = 200;     
    gv.Columns.Add(gvCol); 
    j++;           
}
lbVysledky.View = gv;
```

Then just set the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` to your results object like this:

```
lbVysledky.ItemsSource = results;
```

Also, as a side note, you don's appear to be using the `foreach` construct correctly.  you're enumerating over each column, but you're keeping your own counter and accessing the column like this:

```
gvCol.Header = results.Columns[j].ColumnName;
```

In a `foreach` loop, you're already enumerating the columns with the dc variable, so you can access the column like this:

```
gvCol.Header = dc.ColumnName;
```

and you don't need to manually count the columns (with j).